# mod_rewrite - Prevent multiple redirects

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My folder structure:

```
- nameoftherootfolder
-- app
-- public
--- .htaccess
--- index.php
```

Now I have the problem that in some cases my apache rewrites too often internal that I get an 500 server error, here the log:

```
[Wed Jan 05 17:51:54 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 3 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Jan 05 17:51:54 2011] [debug] core.c(3046): [client 127.0.0.1] r->uri = /nameoftherootfolder/public/index.php
[Wed Jan 05 17:51:54 2011] [debug] core.c(3052): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /nameoftherootfolder/public/index.php
[Wed Jan 05 17:51:54 2011] [debug] core.c(3052): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /nameoftherootfolder/public/index.php
[Wed Jan 05 17:51:54 2011] [debug] core.c(3052): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /nameoftherootfolder/nothere/
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The index.php handles all requests and handle also if the accessed url is wrong, e.g. not exists.

It works if the accessed url exists but it the url is "wrong" I get that error.
I get this just since I set an Apache alias:

```
Alias /nameoftherootfolder/ "C:/somepathshere/WAMP/www/nameoftherootfolder/public/" 

<Directory "C:/somepathshere/WAMP/www/nameoftherootfolder/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

How can I now prevent too many internal redirects with Apache? Is there maybe a RewriteCond?
I'm using Apache 2.2.11.

**Edit:**

If I put a `index.php/` inside the uri it works, but that is SEO unfriendly, user unfriendly and looks horrible, e.g. request.
`http://localhost/nameoftherootfolder/index.php/nothere/` or `http://localhost/nameoftherootfolder/index.php/index/`

**Edit #2:**

After I added

```
RewriteBase /nameoftherootfolder/
```

it works know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After I added

```
RewriteBase /nameoftherootfolder/
```

it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude calls to `index.php` itself to prevent an endless loop.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hm...it seems do have no effect...still getting that error with the same in the apache error log.

Comment: I tried, same result...maybe it's a problem of the alias? Btw. take a look at the edit above.

Comment: @Poru I don't see how this could be a problem with the alias. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a site on a sub-domain under the folder of another site configured in Apache. This fixed my rewrite errors:

```
RewriteBase /
```